# Azure AD B2C Integration in android sample github project

Tags: android-studio, integration, azure-ad-b2c

I was importing the azure ad b2c sample project from github into android studio and got this build error.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

```
Cannot choose between the following variants of project :library:
  - debugRuntimeElements
  - releaseRuntimeElements
All of them match the consumer attributes:
  - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements' capability net.openid:library:86437:
      - Unmatched attributes:
          - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
          - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
          - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
          - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
  - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements' capability net.openid:library:86437:
      - Unmatched attributes:
          - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
          - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
          - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
          - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
```